# Creating a pop up box in Java

Tags: java, popup

I want to create a pop up box that is activated when I click a "Check" button. What it does is ask the user if they are sure about what they requested. If yes, it does the request. If no, it goes back to it's normal state.

I know what I said is a bit ambiguous but I want to create various types of pop up boxes.

So I was wondering is there a website that has generic pop up boxes with the code given?

I just need a simple code which I can expand on.

Comment: Are you using Swing? Or do you work on web application (and in this case, which framework are you using)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [JOptionPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) is what you want.

- `showConfirmDialog`: Asks a confirming
  question, like yes/no/cancel.
- `showInputDialog`:  Prompt for some
  input.
- `showMessageDialog`:   Tell the
  user about something that has
  happened.
- `showOptionDialog`: The Grand
  Unification of the above three.

A small example to get a Yes-No popup like you asked for would be:

```
if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure about your request?", "Request", 
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)
    == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
 //Do the request
}
else
{
 //Go back to normal
}
```

This solution, however, only works if you are using [Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html).

Comment: Indeed, but only if he works on Swing, which could not be necessarily the case...

Comment: @romaintaz True, I'll make note of that

Comment: Yeah I'm using swing, which is this right "import javax.swing.*"?

Comment: @Mr Teeth Yep :-). Then JOptionPane should work fine (or making a custom dialog with JDialog as frm suggested)

Answer (score 3):

You shoudl check [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) to create your custom message dialogs or you can use standard message dialogs in [JOptionPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).