# How to pass a Console output to show as a pop up box in browser

Tags: java, popup

I have a java code which outputs an Alert if it meet some condition. I am setting that value as below.

```
message = "Alert, Net Usage greater than or equal to threshold";
System.out.println(message);
request.setAttribute("message",message);
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsppage.jsp");
 dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

I want to display the "message" in a pop up in the browser. Please help.

Comment: I think `System.out.println` is Java, not Javascript.

Comment: Oh yeah, its is Java. My bad to tag javascript.

Comment: Have you checked out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968964/creating-a-pop-up-box-in-java

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064605/java-servlets-open-message-popup